# How to safely dual boot?

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows right now, and want to work on some potentially malicious stuff. I can't use virtualisation for performance reasons, so I want to dual boot a second windows copy.

How can I make sure my main Windows partition won't be infected? Should I just create a new partition to install Windows 10 and it will be fine? Or are there other precautions to take?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure my main Windows partition won't be infected?

You can never be 100.00% sure, but simply not mounting the other partition will go a long way.

Under windows 10 you can find the relevant interface to mount and unount partitions to folders of drive letters in:

1. Right click on start (aka the windows flag)
2. select run
3. type 'diskmgmt.msc'
4. Right click ont he drive you want to change.
5. select change drive letter and paths.
6. Remove the drive letter or mount point.

[image: Screenshot of diskmanagement]

> Should I just create a new partition to install Windows 10 and it will be fine?

No. Windows has a tendency to alway show all mounted partitions as drive letters. That is easy access for you and easy acces for any malware.

> I can't use virtualisation for performance reasons

Why not? The last time I used virtualisation I archived 98% of the calculation speed of bare metal. Negliable difference. Are you using a special program with lots of syscalls?  Access to a special PCI-e card without passthough? Etc. etc.

If not then virtualisation should be almost as fast, more convenient (no need to switch booted operating systems) and it usually is easier to quickly make a full system backup or to use snapshots.